# Crating a scatterplot out of two dna fasta files in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, biopython

i am currently trying to create a diagram from two fasta dna files.
unfortunately i am not that familiar with python yet which is why i probably fail here and hope for your help
I use Pyhton 3.8 with Biopython, Matplotlib and numpy.

I m trying to convert the dna data into numbers so that i can plot them.
In the meantime i can read the fasta file in my code but not plot it

I can't get any further when converting the dna into a number that is understandable for the plot or is there another way?

Thats my code so far

```
from Bio import pairwise2  
from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment
from test3 import seq1 as fasta1 #seq1 unzipped fasta file
from test3 import seq2 as fasta2 #seq2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy


alignment = pairwise2.align.globalxx(fasta1, fasta2)
print(alignment)
print(format_alignment(*alignment[0]))


plt.scatter(alignment,'skitscat', 'k')
plt.xlabel('fasta1')
plt.ylabel('fasta2')
plt.title('Eins Diagram')
plt.legend()
plt.plot(alignment[0])
plt.show()
```

in the preview you can see how it should look finished.

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiHeI.png)

thank you for your help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. To help others answer your question try describing what attempts you have made so far, what works in the code, what doesn't, and ask specific questions about the concerns you have found.

Comment: i m trying to convert the dna data into numbers so that i can plot them. in the meantime i can read the fasta file in my code but not plot it

Comment: can we have the input files to test your code ?